# Disappearing Widget Text area

Tags: sidebar, widget-text

I recently encountered a strange thing for the first time with Wordpress...all of my text boxes in every widget sidebar disappeared! Other widgets are still there. Has this happened to anyone else? I am using 10 different sidebars on 10 different templates and all text widgets have failed. Is there a limit to how many sidebars you should have? What else could be the problem?

Comment: There are no limits, you should debug your code and possibly disable all plugins and revert to default theme.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know if there was such thing as "overloading" a sidebar.

Comment: My text widgets are dissapearing as well. Have you found what this happens?
Thank you

Comment: I never figured out why, and haven't had the issue since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use [Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/) instead of so many sidebars and that seems to have at leat circumvented the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you must enable debug to true in your wp-config.php file by writing

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
```

to find out what's the exact issue, this will show you all the errors in wordpress dashboard, alternatively you can also check console log in the browser for errors, a proper debugging will probably resolve your issue.